# Call angular function from angular grid column defination

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularJs application where I need to call angular function from hyperlink click.

here is my code

```
vm.gridOptions = {
        data: [],
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,

        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: "LASTNAME",
                displayName: "Last Name",
                cellTemplate: "<div><a href='#' data-ng-click='vm.OpenUserProfilePage({{row.entity[\"USERID\"]}})'>{{row.entity[col.field]}}</a></div>"
            },
            { field: "FIRSTNAME", displayName: "First Name" }
        ]
    };

    vm.getEncryptedUserId = function (userId)
    {
        AdminManageService.getUserIdEncryptedText(userId).then(function (encryptedText)
        {
            return encryptedText;
        });
    }

    vm.OpenUserProfilePage = function(userId) {
        window.location = "/UserProfile.aspx?enkey=" + vm.getEncryptedUserId(userId);
    }
```

Its being rendered correctly in html

```
<a href="#" data-ng-click="vm.OpenUserProfilePage(89)" class="ng-binding">CHW</a>
```

I tried `$event.preventDefault();` too before vm function but didn't work.

Also In console I am getting error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=…w.entity%5B%22USERID%22%5D%7D%7D)&p4=%7Brow.entity%5B%22USERID%22%5D%7D%7D)
```

On click its not even going to `OpenUserProfilePage` method

I am using ui grid : `ui-grid - v3.0.4` with angular version : `AngularJS v1.4.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax is wrong:

```
vm.OpenUserProfilePage({{row.entity[\"USERID\"]}})
```

in your cell template. It should have been:

```
vm.OpenUserProfilePage(row.entity[\"USERID\"])
```

because you cannot mix angular expressions with angular interpolations. For example you cannot do the following:

```
<div ng-show="5 + {{myNumber}} === 8">
```

because ng-show expects an angular expression:

```
<div ng-show="5 + myNumber === 8">
```

If you want to display Yes/No based on this boolean expression:

```
<div>{{(5 + myNumber === 8) ? "True" : "No"}}</div>
```

---

You must use `grid.appScope` to access your application's scope. You are not being helpful by not providing more of your JS and your HTML but if I make some educated assumptions, you must do:

```
data-ng-click='grid.appScope.vm.OpenUserProfilePage(row.entity.USERID)'
```

Comment: it solved console error but html is being rendered as data-ng-click="vm.OpenUserProfilePage(row.entity["USERID"])"

Comment: @Mahajan344 There are too many unknowns. I don't know if you are using ng-grid or ui-grid. I don't know what version. Maybe you should provide a jsfiddle instead?

Comment: I am using ui grid : ui-grid - v3.0.4 with angular version : AngularJS v1.4.3